# Why does UPDATE statement give divide by zero even if that particular row doesn't exist?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Ok this may be idiot question but I want to know why does the update statement gives divided by 0 operation even thought there is no row in the table. Does it execute the set function first and then try to apply to the where clause.

```
  CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
    Id INT,
    Amount money
    )

    UPDATE t
    SET t.Amount=0/0
    FROM #tmp AS t
    WHERE t.Id=2

    DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: this would return an error as you cannot divide by 0

Comment: but here the row doesn't event exists. why try to update if the row doesn't exists

Comment: @WhatsThePoint He knows that already. He wants to know if sql server does the set operation before the where

Comment: @GuidoG it wouldnt even see the `where` as when it is compiled it sees the error and terminates

Comment: Literals are evaluated at parser time so it will raise an exception even before it tries to run. Remember it is not procedural language but rater declarative, it is telling you your declaration is faulty

Answer (score 2):

If you try it like this you will not get an error :

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
Id INT,
Amount money
)

UPDATE t
SET    t.Amount=0/0
FROM   #tmp AS t
WHERE  1 = 0

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

You get the error because your where clause forced a search in your table, and it will peform the set operation also at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Because the query will be parsed before SQL Server attempts to execute it. At that point it will throw an error because the command is unexecutable.

Comment: Also note the error is caught at parser time because you are using literals. If OP instead a column value as divisor it cannot be evaluated at parser time. Same thing if it data to evaluate a variable

Comment: @jean - this isn't the case. These errors are suppressed until runtime. Which is why you can see an estimated plan produced for `SELECT 0/0
FROM master..spt_values` and no error

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*.

Integer division is deterministic and you have an expression (`0/0`) that has no dependency on row values. It therefore seems perfectly reasonable to extract the expression `0/0` out, perform that calculation first, and then use the *result* of that expression as it actually scans through the table. So you get an error because it's not even started any work of processing the table.

In [Guido's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630428/15498), the optimizer found a `WHERE` clause that meant that it could already tell that the query would affect zero rows (without needing to access any statistics about the table) and so it was able to optimize its work even further.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the update statement gives divided by 0 operation even
>   thought there is no row in the table. Does it execute the set function
>   first and then try to apply to the where clause.

Question is not about dived by 0,rather it is about when does any error occur.

BTW query easily pass through "Parse stage" and hand it is handed over to "Optimization" stage.

Example,

> declare @table table(id int identity(1,1),PhoneNumber int)

```
select *,0/0 from @table
```

If you see "`Estimated Execution plan (EEP)`" then there is no error.that means it passes through Parse Stage and also EEP is created.

when we try to view `Actual Execution Plan (AEP)` then we get relevant error or divided by 0 error in this example.

```
select *,case when id=2 then 0/0 else 0 END
 from @table
```

Here again there is no problem in getting EEP.
If we click on AEP then 1 rows is return and get error in 2nd row.

This prove that divided by 0/0 condition are executed when it meet certain condition.

```
select *
 from @table
 where id= case when id=2 then 0/0 else id END
```

Here again there is no problem in getting EEP.
If we click on AEP then 1 rows is return and get error in 2nd row.

This prove that divided by 0/0 condition are executed when it meet certain condition.